# Enable a Field if either of three checkboxes are checked C#

Tags: c#

I have 3 checkboxes and a textbox. If any 1 of those checkboxes is checked then I need the textbox to be enabled, else keep disbaled. I need help with my syntax in C#

Here is my code:

```
if ((Checkbox1=checked) || (Checkbox2=checked) || (Checkbox3=checked))
{
    Textbox.IsEnabled = true;
}
else {Textbox.IsEnabled = false;}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this on one line.

```
Textbox.IsEnabled = Checkbox1.Checked || Checkbox2.Checked || Checkbox3.Checked;
```

EDIT

as it seems you have  `ToggleButton`, you should do

```
Textbox.IsEnabled = Checkbox1.IsChecked || Checkbox2.IsChecked || Checkbox3.IsChecked ;
```

or rather (thinks it's nullable)

```
TextBox.IsEnabled = (Checkbox1.IsChecked.HasValue && Checkbox1.IsChecked.Value) ||
                    (Checbox2.IsChecked.HasValue && Checkbox2.IsChecked.Value) || etc.
```

Comment: I am getting a "'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the lest hand side of += or -=" error. I added  Checkbox.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(Checkbox_Checked); code but it did not help

Comment: @BobbyRicky oh, it was not that clear that it was about `ToggleButton`. See edit maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
bool isEnabled = Checkbox1.Checked || Checkbox2.Checked || Checkbox3.Checked;
TextBoxId.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this to a single command:

```
Textbox.IsEnabled = (Checkbox1.Checked || Checkbox2.Checked || Checkbox3.Checked);
```